# Apache Ignite failing to start GridManagerAdapter in Windows

Tags: caching, ignite

I have downloaded the 2.7.5 binary and trying to run an Ignite node in Windows. These are the errors I am getting (in brief):

1. Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter
2. Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi
3. Local node and remote node have different version numbers

This is my config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="TestCache"/>
                    <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                    <property name="backups" value="1"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <!-- Enabling Apache Ignite Persistent Store. -->
        <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                        <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All server and thick-clients need to be on the same version of Ignite. (There are commercial versions of Ignite that allow you to mix versions, but even that's really only designed for you to upgrade your cluster without downtime.)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do that? I am running from the 2.7.5bin only. I have attached the configuration xml above.

Comment: You said "Local node and remote node have different version numbers." Local and remote need to have the _same_ version. If you run 2.7.5 on the server, you need to have 2.7.5 on the client side.

Comment: I have only downloaded the binary and executed "bin\ignite.bat PATH_TO_XML" with the above xml. Can you throw some light on this?

Comment: If it's not your node, it must be someone else on your subnet. Maybe switch to using the `TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder`, that way it's not going to pick up other clusters.

Answer (score 0):

Error is pretty clear: you can not mix nodes with different versions inside a single cluster. Most likely you already have a running 2.7.0 process somewhere, probably inside another machine.

First, try replace **TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder** with static **TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder**. This will force a node to connect only to provided list of IP addresses. Whereas TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder will try to scan your network for running nodes if it fails to connect from predefined address list.

Also check running JAVA Ignite processes and kill them if required.